# Correctly Using the Shift Function in Data.Table

Tags: r, data.table

I have this dataset in which students take an exam multiple times over a period of years - a "fail" is a 0 and a "pass" is a 1. The data looks something like this:

```
# Load the data.table package
library(data.table)

# Generate some sample data
id = sample.int(10000, 100000, replace = TRUE)
res = c(1,0)
results = sample(res, 100000, replace = TRUE)
date_exam_taken = sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2020/01/01'), by="day"), 100000, replace = TRUE)

# Create a data table from the sample data
my_data = data.table(id, results, date_exam_taken)
my_data <- my_data[order(id, date_exam_taken)]

# Generate some additional columns for each record
my_data$general_id = 1:nrow(my_data)
my_data$exam_number = ave(my_data$general_id, my_data$id, FUN = seq_along)
my_data$general_id = NULL

   id results date_exam_taken exam_number
1:  1       0      2002-10-06           1
2:  1       1      2003-07-21           2
3:  1       1      2003-10-15           3
4:  1       0      2005-07-21           4
5:  1       1      2014-08-22           5
6:  1       1      2015-09-11           6
```

I want to track the number of times each student failed an exam, given that they failed the two previous exams (and all such combinations). I tried to do this with the data.table library in R:

```
# Create new columns that contain the previous exam results
my_data$prev_exam = shift(my_data$results, 1)
my_data$prev_2_exam = shift(my_data$results, 2)
my_data$prev_3_exam = shift(my_data$results, 3)

# Count the number of exam results for each record
out <- my_data[!is.na(prev_exam), .(tally = .N), by = .(id, results, prev_exam, prev_2_exam, prev_3_exam)]

out = na.omit(out)

> head(out)
   id results prev_exam prev_2_exam prev_3_exam tally
1:  1       1         1           1           1     1
2:  1       0         1           1           1     3
3:  1       0         0           1           1     2
4:  1       1         0           0           1     1
5:  1       0         1           0           0     1
6:  1       1         0           1           0     1
```

**Can someone please tell me if I have done this correctly? Have I correctly used the "shift()" function in data.table?**

Comment: Do not use `$<-` with data.tables. Use `:=`. You need to shift `by = id`. I do not understand what you are doing after "I then tried to summarize this information".

Comment: Also use one call to shift to get all three at once. I think you're looking for `my_data[, shift(results, 2:0), by=id][!is.na(V1), .N, keyby=.(V1, V2, V3)]`

Comment: @ Roland - thank youfror your reply! I am trying to calculate the probability of a student failing an exam, given that the student failed the two previous exams. I would like to estimate this probability by taking into consideration the trends within the whole data.

Comment: @ Ronald and @ Frank: I mixed up the code from two different problems I am working on- can you please see the update? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`shift` is being used correctly, but it's hard to tell what is going on once we get to `my_grid$counts = as.integer(rnorm(8,10,5))`.

One thing, though. The table should be filtered on `!is.na(prev_3_exam)` instead of `!is.na(prev_exam)`.

Here is a function that uses a similar approach to return `out` and `my_grid` in a list for the `lag` specified as a parameter. It uses `data.table` grouping rather than a `for` loop.

```
f1 <- function(dt, lag = 1L) {
  if (!identical(key(dt), c("id", "date_exam_taken"))) setkey(dt, id, date_exam_taken)
  nms <- paste0("exam", 1:lag)
  
  list(
    out = dt2 <- copy(dt)[
      ,(nms) := shift(results, 1:lag) # see Frank's comment
    ][
      id == shift(id, lag)
    ][
      , .(tally = .N), by = c("id", "results", nms)
    ],
    my_grid = setorderv(
      dt2[
        , {
          counts <- sum(tally)
          .(
            counts = counts,
            probability = sum(results*tally)/counts
          )
        }, nms
      ], rev(nms)
    )
  )
}
```

Output:

```
f1(dt, 3L)
#> $out
#>           id results exam1 exam2 exam3 tally
#>     1:     1       0     0     1     1     1
#>     2:     1       1     0     0     1     1
#>     3:     1       0     1     0     0     1
#>     4:     1       1     0     1     0     2
#>     5:     1       1     1     0     1     2
#>    ---                                      
#> 57437: 10000       1     0     0     0     1
#> 57438: 10000       0     1     0     0     1
#> 57439: 10000       1     0     1     0     1
#> 57440: 10000       0     1     0     1     1
#> 57441: 10000       0     0     1     0     1
#> 
#> $my_grid
#>    exam1 exam2 exam3 counts probability
#> 1:     0     0     0   8836   0.4980761
#> 2:     1     0     0   8832   0.5005661
#> 3:     0     1     0   8684   0.4947029
#> 4:     1     1     0   8770   0.4976055
#> 5:     0     0     1   8792   0.5013649
#> 6:     1     0     1   8631   0.5070096
#> 7:     0     1     1   8806   0.5021576
#> 8:     1     1     1   8682   0.4997696
```

If only `my_grid` is needed, here is a function wrapping an `Rcpp` function that uses bit shifting to perform the aggregation in a single-pass `for` loop without creating the helper columns with `shift`. It will be very fast, and its speed will be only marginally affected by the value of `lag`.

```
Rcpp::cppFunction("
  IntegerVector exam_contingency(const IntegerVector& id, const IntegerVector& result, const int& lag) {
    const int n = id.size();
    const int lag1 = lag + 1;
    int comb = result(0);
    int mask = ~(1 << lag1);
    IntegerVector out(pow(2, lag1));
    
    for (int i = 1; i < lag1; i++) comb = (comb << 1) + result(i);
    out(comb) = id(lag) == id(0);

    for (int i = lag1; i < n; i++) {
      comb = ((comb << 1) + result(i)) & mask;
      out(comb) += id(i - lag) == id(i);
    }
    
    return(out);
}
")

f2 <- function(dt, lag = 1L) {
  if (!identical(key(dt), c("id", "date_exam_taken"))) setkey(dt, id, date_exam_taken)
  m <- matrix(
    exam_contingency(dt$id, dt$results, as.integer(lag)),
    2^lag, 2, 1
  )
  rs <- rowSums(m)
  cbind(
    if (lag == 1L) {
      data.frame(exam1 = 0:1)
    } else {
      setNames(
        expand.grid(rep(list(0:1), lag)),
        paste0("exam", 1:lag)
      )
    },
    data.frame(counts = rs, probability = m[,2]/rs)
  )
}
```

It gives the same output as `f1`'s `my_grid`:

```
all.equal(f1(dt, 3L)$my_grid, setDT(f2(dt, 3L)))
#> [1] TRUE
```

Benchmarking:

```
#> Unit: microseconds
#>        expr    min      lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
#>   f1(dt, 3) 8802.2 9706.70 11478.458 10394.00 12134.40 69630.0   100
#>   f2(dt, 3)  971.2 1016.40  1179.404  1047.20  1108.65  7733.8   100
#>  f2(dt, 10) 1181.3 1208.05  1256.333  1237.65  1302.40  1406.6   100
```

Data:

```
library(data.table)
(seed <- sample(.Machine$integer.max, 1))
#> [1] 1784920766
set.seed(seed)
dt <- data.table(
  id = sample.int(10000, 100000, replace = TRUE),
  results = sample(0:1, 100000, replace = TRUE),
  date_exam_taken = sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2020/01/01'), by="day"), 100000, replace = TRUE)
)
setkey(dt, id, date_exam_taken)
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! Can you please comment on my original approach?

Comment: Not much beyond what I, Roland, and Frank have already said. As I mentioned, I don't fully follow what is going on after `my_grid$counts = as.integer(rnorm(8,10,5))`, but it is better to use `data.table`'s grouping operations rather than repeatedly subsetting within a `for` loop.

Comment: I am so sorry - I mixed up the code from two different problems I am working - can you please see the update? Thanks!

Comment: In that case, I have nothing more to add. It all looks correct (though not optimal), except for `!is.na(prev_exam)` as I pointed out.